# Xamarin Public Class data how to acess it properly

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I get data from another page with

```
var check = new check
            {
                Age = (int)Convert.ToInt64(Ageg)
            };
            
            var secondPage = new Sdeduction ();
            secondPage.BindingContext = check;
            await Navigation.PushAsync(secondPage);
```

and received on

```
public class check
    {
        public int Age { get; set;  }
    }
public Sdeduction()
            {    
    InitializeComponent();    
        
    }
```

but I am unable to access Age for some calculation directly. lile tta.Text = Age.ToString();

So I use binding. Which work well.

```
 <Label x:Name="Ages" Text="{Binding Age}"></Label>
```

but i want to check for Age which data get passed between page but I'm unable to figure it out I try

```
public Sdeduction()
        {    
InitializeComponent();    
    int aged = (int)Convert.ToInt64(Ages.Text);
        if (aged == 0)
           {
             TTA.IsVisible = true;
           }
        if(aged > 0)
           {
             TTB.IsVisible = true;
             //Ds.IsVisible = true;
            }
}
```

But it is Ages.Text is null.

**Main issue is how to get data from public class check**

```
  public class check
    {
        public int Age { get; set;  }
    }
```

How can able to get this public int in other part of c#. where get passed data by

I can able to bind but https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/ is all about the binding property and context on the xaml level. I like to get data from other page but only can able to bind with the x:names Ages but nothing much as when page load/InitializeComponent it don't have names of ages.

Comment: Please read any tutorial about binding. You shouldn't be trying to access `Ages.text`. You should be accessing a "bound" variable, `Age2`. (I gave it that name, to avoid confusion with the `Age` you already have elsewhere.) `Age2` should be in the `BindingContext` for your page, and `Deduction` needs to set it. Suppose the class you use as a BindingContext is named `MyViewModel`. Then you can access during page load as `((MyViewModel)BindingContext).Age2`.

Comment: ok i actually able to bind and may be after page rendered can run some funtion that will help .But my main issue is getting data which passed by the this way. https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/DataBindingDemos/README.md kind off stuck in new language for more then week. If help i am very thankfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the BindingContext of the Sdeduction instance to the check instance, and then navigates to the Sdeduction. It's the right way to pass data when navigating.

But when you check for Age as page load in Sdeduction() method, it always get 0 before the Sdeduction page set the BindingContext. You nned to load in OnAppearing() method.

MainPage:

xaml:

```
  <StackLayout>
    <Label x:Name="label" Text="10" />
    <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked" Text="Navigate" />
</StackLayout>
```

Code behind:

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    string Ageg;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Ageg = label.Text;
    }

    async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var check = new check
        {
            Age = (int)Convert.ToInt64(Ageg)
        };

        var secondPage = new Sdeduction();
        secondPage.BindingContext = check;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(secondPage);
    }

}
```

Sdeduction:

Xaml:

```
<StackLayout>
        <Label
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            Text="Welcome to Sdeduction!"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

        <Label x:Name="Ages" Text="{Binding Age}" />

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button
                x:Name="TTA"
                IsVisible="false"
                Text="TTA" />
            <Button
                x:Name="TTB"
                IsVisible="false"
                Text="TTB" />
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

Code behind:

```
   protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        int aged = (int)Convert.ToInt64(Ages.Text);
        if (aged == 0)
        {
            TTA.IsVisible = true;
        }
        if (aged > 0)
        {
            TTB.IsVisible = true;
            //Ds.IsVisible = true;
        }

    }
```

Please check the screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cK1Wf.jpg

Comment: Is there is any simple way to just get pass passed between pages in int which able to access in whole page.

Comment: You could try to pass data through a page constructor. Check the link below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical#passing-data-through-a-page-constructor