# CollectionView template calls converter incorrectly

Tags: xamarin.forms, valueconverter

Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2012, Visual Studio 2019 for Mac 8.10.16

I am encountering a problem (on both iOS and Android, on both emulators and physical devices) trying to call a Converter in the XAML describing a new screen in our app. This is the markup:

```
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:internal="clr-namespace:Views.Shared"
    x:Class="Views.EditPage">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <internal:PictureNameToImageSourceConverter x:Key="PictureNameToImageSourceConverter" />
    </ContentPage.Resources>
```

...

```
    <CollectionView
        x:Name="picturesView"
        ItemsLayout="HorizontalList"
        HeightRequest="90">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Frame HasShadow="False" Padding="5">
                    <Image
                      HeightRequest="80"
                      Source="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource PictureNameToImageSourceConverter}}" />
                </Frame>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

The **CollectionView.ItemsSource** value is set in code to a **List<string>** instance. When the **List** has no items, the screen displays correctly. When it does have items the app crashes as the screen appears. If I launch the app attached to the VS debugger, the screen freezes before the crash, and I never get any information.

This converter is well tested and is used several other places in the app with no problem. When I replace the **Image** with `<Label Text="{Binding Path=.}"/>` the text items are displayed as expected, so it doesn't look like a binding or `Path` syntax error.

Is there something I'm not seeing or not aware of in the markup that's causing this? Or can anyone suggest further debugging I haven't thought of?

---

**UPDATE**

> A breakpoint on the very first line of the converter was never reached.

**EDIT** in response to comments:

From the **EditPage** codebehind:

```
    public partial class EditPage : ContentPage
    {
        internal List<string> PictureNames;
```

...

```
        protected override void OnAppearing( )
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            picturesView.ItemsSource = PictureNames;
        }
```

The **PictureNames** property is actually set by a different **Page** to which one navigates from the **EditPage**:

```
        private void saveSelection_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs args)
        {
            creator.PictureNames = new List<string>();
            foreach (SelectableItem<Picture> item in pictureItems)
            {
                if (item.IsSelected)
                {
                    creator.PictureNames.Add(item.Item.PictureName);
                }
            }

            Navigation.PopAsync();
        }
```

**pictureItems** is a **List** acting as a **ListView.ItemsSource** on that screen, where pictures are selected or unselected.

**UPDATE**

After much setting of breakpoints, I've determined that the line `picturesView.ItemsSource = PictureNames;` is where the crash happens. It seems odd that it only happens when the template is showing an **Image**, but not a **Label**, seeing that the converter is never actually called.

**UPDATE**

The trick of adding the delay did get me to the breakpoint. And what I found is more puzzling than ever: The **value** parameter being passed to the **Convert** method of our converter is **null**. This is the case whether coming back from the picture selection screen, or if I set the bound list in response to a **Button** rather than in **OnAppearing**,  or if I just set it right in the page constructor.

In addition, when setting a breakpoint on the crashing line, when the display element in the template is a **Label** everything is as expected, but when the display element is an **Image** the debugger freezes when trying to look at those values. The problem is apparently something about the fact of calling a converter in this precise situation.

I tested that by adding a different converter to the template:

```
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Frame HasShadow="False" Padding="5" HeightRequest="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource PictureNameToHeightConverter}}">
        <Label Text="{Binding Path=.}" />
    </Frame>
    </DataTemplate>
</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

Exactly the same result: The **value** parameter passed to the **Convert** method is **null** even though the same bound value in the same template instance is displayed in the **Label**. If I set a breakpoint on the line assigning the **ItemsSource** property as before, the debugger freezes.

**UPDATE**

Finally beginning to suspect that I'm triggering some corner case bug in the framework, I replaced the **CollectionView** with a **CarouselView**, and it works correctly:

```
<CarouselView
    x:Name="picturesView"
    HeightRequest="90">
    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        <Frame HasShadow="False" Padding="5">
            <Image
            HeightRequest="80"
            Source="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource PictureNameToImageSourceConverter}}" />
        </Frame>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```

I'm adding this as an update to the question rather than as an answer because I still don't actually know the explanation.

Comment: If you think the converter is causing the crash, why did you not post that code?  Does the converter have any exception handling code?

Comment: I should clarify the title. I do not think the converter is causing the crash.

Comment: That seems like the likely culprit to me.  If you swap the Image for a Label and the crash stops, then that seems significant.  Have you checked the logs for any relevant messages?  Do you have any crash reporting tools setup?

Comment: Suggestions: Wrap code inside converter with `try-catch`. Put a breakpoint in the converter. And/or a Debug.WriteLine in the converter. Sounds like there is some problem converting one of the strings in the list into an image.

Comment: That was a good thought. A breakpoint on the very first line of the converter was never reached.

Comment: Show in question this code: 1) declaration of list being shown. 2) the line(s) of code that create/set the list of items. 3) What method contains (or calls) those lines of code to create the items - is this from an App method (such as Startup)? In a constructor (if so, of which class)? Or `OnAppearing`? Or some other event method?

Comment: I've added this code as you suggest, but it's unclear if it can help. When we show a **Label** in place of an **Image** the contents of the **List** populating the **CollectionView** are exactly as we expect them to be.

Comment: It may seem trivial, but please also add the declaration of PictureNames. I want to see the exact type, and whether it is a field or property. (This may also help people in the future who see this Q&A.)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Done - I added the declaration to the top of the codebehind snippets.

Comment: I'd like to see the source of both `PictureNameToImageSourceConverter `and the one that converts to height. Must be something about accessing an image during the conversion. Maybe the image gets disposed when it shouldn't. Though I don't know why CarouselView would treat it differently.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen some odd behavior when updating page details in `OnAppearing`.

Hard to put a finger on exactly when there will be a problem, but the fact that you navigated to another page, so this is `OnAppearing` during the "back" from that other page is probably a factor.

Try this:

```
protected override void OnAppearing( )
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( async () => {
        // Let the page appear on screen, before setting ItemsSource.
        await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(200);
        picturesView.ItemsSource = PictureNames;
    });
}
```

At minimum, this should allow Xamarin to reach the breakpoint in the converter.

——————-

**UPDATE**

I don’t see any obvious flaw in the code you’ve posted.

You’ve narrowed it down to the line it crashes on.
Yet a breakpoint at start of converter is never reached.
As you say, this is a puzzling combination of facts.

Here is a test to do:

- Put breakpoint on the line that crashes.
- Copy the values in the list, to a text editor.
- Add a button on the current page, that when pressed, fills the list with those same strings, hardcoded as a literal, then sets the ItemSource.
- Start over, but this time press the button - Does this work or crash?

That is, remove all the complexity of going to another page, querying values, returning to this page.

I bet this will work. Then you’d have the best situation for debugging: a case that works vs. one that doesn’t.

After that, its “divide and conquer”. Start making the working one more like the broken one, and/or vice versa, until the culprit is identified.

Comment: I've updated the question in response to trying your suggestions here. I'm about half a day from just going old school and adding the images to the EditPage one at a time "by hand".

Answer (score 0):

You could try to pass data with the ways below when you do the navigation.

**One way is to set the `BindingContext` to the page which you want to navigate to.**

Use the Navigation.PushAsync to navigate the page and reset the `BindingContext` before the page navigated. You could check the thread i done before for more details. [Xamarin Public Class data how to acess it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66944238/xamarin-public-class-data-how-to-acess-it-properly/66948683#66948683)

Or you could try to binding to a path property using MVVM.

```
  <Image HeightRequest="80" Source="{Binding path, Converter={StaticResource PictureNameToImageSourceConverter}}" />
```

**Another way is to pass the data to the page which you want to navigate through a Page Constructor.**

For more details of this way, check the MS docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical#passing-data-through-a-page-constructor

Answer (score 0):

While it would be interesting to know why the **CollectionView** binding isn't behaving as expected in this specific situation, the number of hours spent trying to figure it out has definitely passed the point of diminishing returns, so I just added the images the old-fashioned way. I replaced the **CollectionView** with a **StackLayout**:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="picturesLayout" Orientation="Horizontal" />
```

And then just added framed images "by hand" in the **OnAppearing** method:

```
picturesLayout.Children.Clear();
foreach (string pictureName in PictureNames)
{
    picturesLayout.Children.Add(new Frame { Padding = 5, HasShadow = false, Content = new Image { Source = ImageManager.ReadFromDisk(pictureName), HeightRequest = 80 } });
}
```

(**ImageManager** handles chores like keeping track of the full path to the appropriate directory.)